# What were 12 year old Pitts' objections to Principia Mathematica?

Tags: biographical-details, mathematical-logic, debunking

In Wikipedia on the page dedicated to Walter Pitts (accesses today), it is written that,

> He is widely remembered to have spent three days in a library, at the age of 12, reading *Principia Mathematica* and sent a letter to Bertrand Russell pointing out what he considered serious problems with the first half of the first volume. Russell was appreciative and invited him to study in the United Kingdom.

My questions are,

1. What were his objections specifically?
2. Is there any copy of his letter that is freely downloadable?
3. What was Russell's reply to him? Is there any copy of his letter that is freely downloadable?

Comment: I cannot locate any additional information about the Russell episode, however Pitts apparently had a similar issue with one of Carnap's books.  He travelled to the U of Chicago where Carnap enjoyed tenure.  Carnap took a copy of his book down from his bookshelf and upon examining the point highlighted by Pitts, he agreed that it was very poorly explained. See N. Smalheiser's paper [Walter Pitts](http://abel.lis.illinois.edu/tutorial/smalheiser_pitts_2000.pdf).

Comment: Maybe we have to ask at the Project [The Collected Letters of Bertrand Russell](http://russell.mcmaster.ca/brletters.htm) hosted at McMaster University.

Comment: I have already sent an email to the Project Director Nicholas Griffin @MauroALLEGRANZA.

Comment: Godd job ! I hope we can "share" the answer :-) Now I'm very curious... also if my **personal** feeling is that - if the letter exists - we will not find in it "big" discoveries: maybe typos and some comments regarding "obscure" points of the "philsophical" part of *Principia* (the more difficult and debated).

Comment: Sometime ago I received Nicholas Griffin's reply to my email. He said, "..I know very little about this, but the topic does come up from time to time. I can tell you that there are no letters either from or to Pitt in the Russell Archives".

Comment: @Conifold: See the above.

Comment: Not sure if the Russell story came from McCulloch. There is an interview with Lettvin which mentioned it too. Lettvin, J. Y. (1998b). [Interview with J.A. Anderson and E. Rosenfeld]. In J. A. Anderson & E. Rosenfeld (Eds.),
Talking nets: An oral history of neural networks (pp. 1– 21). Cambridge MA: MIT Press A transcript can be found here: https://repository.library.brown.edu/studio/collections/id_788/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This story bears characteristic signs of a tall tale, although in this case one can identify the origin. It appears to be an amalgamation of two anecdotes, neither of which is itself very credible. Both are traceable to [Warren McCulloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Sturgis_McCulloch), Pitts's co-author on "A Logical Calculus of Ideas Immanent in Nervous Activity" (1943), which proposed the first mathematical model of a neural network. There is some vague connection to actual events, which might have prompted the story's retelling.

"He is widely remembered to have spent three days" reading Principia in the library, says Wikipedia, without naming any sources of this wide rememberance. Upon closer examination the story is interpolated from [Talking Nets by Anderson-Rosenfeld](https://books.google.com/books?id=-l-yim2lNRUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Talking+Nets:+An+Oral+History+of+Neural+Networks&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=cQi3TZT2PIrj0QH61_zFCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-thumbnail&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6wEwAA#v=onepage&q=walter%20pitts&f=false), not exactly a historical work, and the more reputable [Smalheiser's short biography of Pitts](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/46504). Both name McCulloch as the anecdote's source, Smalheiser even references his Collected Works:

> "*The story is told that, at age 12, Pitts ran into the public library to hide from some bullies, found a copy of Principia Mathematica by the 20th-century philosophers Bertrand Russell and Alfred North Whitehead, and proceeded to read it cover to cover in the next few weeks [1]. Pitts experienced a metaphysical insight that logic rules the universe,  and  as  a  corollary  he  felt  that  ego — and  his  ego  in  particular — needed  to  be  erased  in  order  to  achieve  an  understanding  of  the  world.*"

There is no mention of the letter here, and "the story is told" is an odd way to introduce a story one believes. He then quotes the other story, about Pitts meeting "Bert" in a park in Chicago when he ran away from home at 15 (Anderson-Rosenfeld make him 14 for that). And then

> "*Now,  this  Bert  talked  with  Walter  for  some time of philosophy and mathematics, and came to realize that this was no ordinary youngster.  Bert  was  impressed.  He  told  the  boy  that  Carnap,  then  Professor  of Philosophy  at  the  University  of  Chicago,  had  written  a  book  that  would  interest
>   him, and urged him to go and speak to the grand old man. So, Walter got himself
>   a  copy  of  Carnap’s  book  and  read  it.  Later,  Carnap  was  to  recount  the  meeting thus: “This young boy came in to see me and said he had read my book and that a certain  paragraph  on  a  certain  page  was  not  clear  to  him...*"

Guess who told this story. It was Blum with reference to... McCulloch. This time Smalheiser is even more explicit about its credibility:

> "*Though the story of meeting “Bert” in this manner may be apocryphal, it
>   is true that Pitts sat in on Bertrand Russell’s course when the latter visited
>   Chicago  in  1938,  and  that  he  walked  into  Rudolf  Carnap’s  office  with  a marked  copy  of  his  book  filled  with  corrections  and  suggested  improvements. After his initial contact with Carnap, he disappeared, and almost a year went by before Carnap was able to contact him again, supervise some
>   of his studies, and help him secure a student job.*"

In 1938 Pitts was indeed 15, but there is no mention that the marked copy of Carnap's book survived, however. And even if we are to believe McCulloch's recollections, the alleged letter, let alone Russell's reply to it, are additions by later "contributors".